# How can I fix the error in installing xmgrace in Mac Mojave?

Tags: homebrew, macos-mojave, xmgrace

I tried to install xmgrace via brew with the command `brew install grace`, but then following error occurs:

> Can't open display
>   Failed initializing GUI, exiting

I operate in the bash shell on a macOS Mojave10.14.6.

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try below command to solve your issue:**

```
$ DISPLAY=:0.0 xmgrace
```

if it doesn’t solve the problem, you need to open XQuartz and then enter the following command:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0.0 xmgrace
```

Comment: in my case "$echo $DISPLAY" gives ":0". 
shall I set $DISPLAY to something specific?